# Why Ascending Sort C++ Cant Work Properly?

Tags: c++

what is the error in the source code if you want to sort ascending based on time?

struct pelari
{ char nama[10];int jam,menit,detik,usia,total;}
pelari lari[10]

int main()
{
int i,n,j,tmp

cout<<"Masukan banyak peserta :";
cin>>n;

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=i;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(lari[i].total>lari[j])
        {
            tmp=lari[j].total;
            lari[j].total=lari[i].total;
            lari[j]=tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if(lari[i].total>lari[j]) shold do?

Comment: What type is "lari"?

Comment: "what is the error" That's the thing *you* should tell *us*. Do you get compiler error? Runtime error? Incorrect output? Please provide [mcve]

Comment: SO is meant to solve the errors, not to find the errors and solve. So, you need to find the error and edit the question a bit.'

Comment: there is nothing error indication but the code not work, i want do sort ascending but 
when displaying the results nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `std::sort` with an appropriate comparer

```
std::sort(std::begin(lari), std::end(lari), [](auto & lhs, auto & rhs) { return lhs.total > rhs.total; });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the way you used to compare `lari[i].total>lari[j]`; I think that you should fix with `lari[i].total>lari[j].total`.
But, looking in deeper, I think that there is also a problem in the "exchange", since you should have:

```
tmp=lari[j].total;
lari[j].total=lari[i].total;
lari[i].total=tmp;
```

So, the code becomes:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    for(j=i;j<n;j++) {
        if(lari[i].total>lari[j].total) {
            tmp=lari[j].total;
            lari[j].total=lari[i].total;
            lari[i].total=tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Try with this. Bye!

Comment: Just use `std::swap`. Reinventing the wheel is asking for problems.

Comment: but std::swap cant use in iostream

Comment: @ChristianLie You can use `std::swap` whereever you want, what do you mean?